# How can add a Xcode project into another project?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I've create two apps, I want to embed an App into another app, ie., I want to include an app into another app and these apps should be run together, is it possible? If yes, please tell me step by step instructions. I've added a project to another project, but while running the parent project is running but not the child app? Please could you tell how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new build target in a project and add the source files of the new project to it and even share common used source files. There is a WWDC video about migrating an app form iOS to OSX look it up. Somewhere it explains how to do ti.